# perl - file handling

Tags: perl, ssh, directory, file-handling

I have a list of files on host machine say in directory /src/.
The directory has more subdirectories. now this directory is copied onto remote machine after mounting. Now the files are preset in remote machine in directory /dst.

Example. If I had /src/a/f1, /src/b/f2
I will have on remote machine /dst/a/f1 ,/dst/b/f2

Now I only have information on host directory,host file. Using this information how do I access files on remote machine using ssh in perl. I would have to cd to /dst and read files from there. How do I do this cd and read in one single ssh command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it all without delegating to `/usr/bin/ssh`, check out [Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/Net-SSH2-0.31/lib/Net/SSH2.pm), and [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/PathTools-3.31/lib/File/Spec.pm)

You'll need `scp_get ( remote [, local ] )`

It will look something like this.

```
use File::Spec ();
use Net::SSH2 ();
my ( $vol, $dir, $file ) = File::Spec::splitpath( $path );
my @dirs = File::Spec::splitdir( $dir );

## Change the root dir
$dirs[0] = 'dst'; # new_root_dir

my $new_remote_path = File::Spec::catfile( @dirs, $file );

  ## Almost right from Net::SSH2 SYNOPSIS
  my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
  $ssh2->connect('example.com') or die $!;
  if ($ssh2->auth_keyboard('fizban')) {

      my $sftp = $ssh2->sftp();

      my $fh = $sftp->open('/etc/passwd') or die;
      print $_ while <$fh>;

      ## or $ssh2->scp_get( $new_remote_path );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling 'man ssh' comes up with the SSH manual page.  I followed the first link ( http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1 ), from which we see the following.  Interesting parts are specified.

> **ssh** [-1246AaCfgkMNnqsTtVvXxY] [-b
>   bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D
>   port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
>   [-i identity_file] [-L
>   [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l
>   login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd]
>   [-o option] [-p port] [-R
>   [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S
>   ctl_path] [user@]hostname [**command**]
>
> ...
>
> ssh (SSH client) is a program for
>   logging into a remote machine and for
>   executing commands on a remote
>   machine.  It is intended to replace
>   rlogin and rsh, and provide secure
>   encrypted communications between two
>   untrusted hosts over an insecure
>   network.  X11 connections and arbitrary
>   TCP/IP ports can also be forwarded
>   over the secure channel.
>
> ssh connects and logs into the
>   specified hostname (with optional user
>   name).  The user must prove his/her
>   identity to the remote machine using
>   one of several methods depending on
>   the protocol version used.
>
> **If command is specified, command is executed on the remote host instead of
>   a login shell.**

So, try `ssh user@hostname ls -lR /src/`, replacing 'ls -lR' with whatever command you actually want.

EDIT
Oh, and look at the man page for the identity file - if you have keys set up, you can use that to avoid providing a password to SSH on the command line.  And make sure the whole path to your identity file has strong permissions, so nobody else can read/replace/edit it.